# navigating to another child on button click

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xlpagertabstrip

am using https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip#how-to-change-the-visible-child-view-controller-programmatically in my application ...

on button click from one child i want to move to another child .. i tried:

```
@IBAction func morenewsbtn(_ sender: Any) {
    print("clicked")
    let mainpage = HomeViewController()
    mainpage.moveToViewController(at: 1, animated: true)
}
```

but this will not move to another child .. tried this in viewdidappear and its working fine .. but how to use it in button click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because this

```
let mainpage = HomeViewController() // problem is here
mainpage.moveToViewController(at: 1, animated: true)
```

is a new VC , you need to make it from the presented one , you can either set a reference to home , or simply use this

```
let home = self.parent as! HomeViewController
parent.moveToViewController(at: 1)
```

Comment: i want to make it from child .. this button is a child 0 and i want to go to 1 when button clicked in it .. HomeViewController is the parent view